# Evitar volver a la pantalla del login con usuario logueado en Angular-Fullstack generator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con el generador [Angular-Fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) de Yeoman. Este framework genera automáticamente un login con el protocolo [OAuth](https://oauth.net/).

Para acceder al sistema, es obligatorio loguearse, por lo que la página principal es el login. Una vez accedido al sistema, si el usuario vuelve hacia atrás, se muestra la página de login de nuevo, pero con el usuario todavía en sesión.

Lo que quiero conseguir, es que al volver atrás se salte a la página previa al login.

Dejo el código donde el generador modifica las cookies:

**auth.service.js**

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  function AuthService($location, $http, $cookies, $q, appConfig, Util, User) {
    var safeCb = Util.safeCb;
    var currentUser = {};
    var userRoles = appConfig.userRoles || [];

    if ($cookies.get('token') && $location.path() !== '/logout') {
      currentUser = User.get();
    }

    var Auth = {

      /**
       * Authenticate user and save token
       *
       * @param  {Object}   user     - login info
       * @param  {Function} callback - optional, function(error, user)
       * @return {Promise}
       */
      login({
        email,
        password
      }, callback) {
        return $http.post('/auth/local', {
            email: email,
            password: password
          })
          .then(res => {
            $cookies.put('token', res.data.token);
            currentUser = User.get();
            return currentUser.$promise;
          })
          .then(user => {
            safeCb(callback)(null, user);
            return user;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            Auth.logout();
            safeCb(callback)(err.data);
            return $q.reject(err.data);
          });
      },

      /**
       * Delete access token and user info
       */
      logout() {
        $cookies.remove('token');
        currentUser = {};
      },

      /**
       * Check if a user is logged in
       *   (synchronous|asynchronous)
       *
       * @param  {Function|*} callback - optional, function(is)
       * @return {Bool|Promise}
       */
      isLoggedIn(callback) {
        if (arguments.length === 0) {
          return currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role');
        }

        return Auth.getCurrentUser(null)
          .then(user => {
            var is = user.hasOwnProperty('role');
            safeCb(callback)(is);
            return is;
          });
      },

      /**
       * Get auth token
       *
       * @return {String} - a token string used for authenticating
       */
      getToken() {
        return $cookies.get('token');
      }
    };

    return Auth;
  }

  angular.module('tachologyApp.auth')
    .factory('Auth', AuthService);
})();
```

Comment: Hola nash. Me parece que a tu pregunta le faltan datos clave. Te recomiendo que sigas esta guía [_"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"_](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorarla.

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi pregunta, espero que ahora quede más claro!

Comment: @nash Debes mostrar algún detalle de que sistema de rutas estas usando, ui-router o ngRouter?

Comment: Disculpa, se me olvidó comentarlo. Estoy usando ui-router.. Estoy barajando la posibilidad de resetear la caché (no sé si es lo más adecuado) o restringir la función "window.history.back()"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo comprueba en el controller del login si estas autenticado ya y redirecciona a otra página

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function(Auth, $state) {
   if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
       // Usas return para que el resto del controller no siga ejecutando
       // También puedes usar un else
       return $state.go('estado_inicial');
   }
});
```

Si el código anterior parece no hacer nada envuelve la llamada en un `$timeout`

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function(Auth, $state, $timeout) {
   if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
       return $timeout(function() {
           $state.go('estado_inicial');
       });
   }
});
```

Por último puedes usar el [evento](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) `$stateChangeStart` y ubicar toda esa lógica ahí

```
.run(function($rootScope, Auth, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
        if (toState.name === 'login' && Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }
    });
});
```